# Pine-Script to Python Why the Converted "On Balance Volume -OBV indicator" not matching with TradingView chart value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pine-script, tradingview-api

I have been trying to get python coded pandas logic output exactly same as the trading view chart output for "OBV - On Balcance Volume"

some of the Pine Script Reference for OBV:

```
study(title="On Balance Volume", shorttitle="OBV")
src = close
obv = cum(change(src) > 0 ? volume : change(src) < 0 ? -volume : 0*volume)
plot(obv, color=blue, title="Price_OBV")
```

Calculation method given in Tradingview Wiki Page

On Balance Volume has one of the more straightforward calculations in technical analysis. It is simply addition or subtraction based on a few conditions.

> 1. If Current Closing Price is greater than the Prior Closing Price then:    Previous OBV + Current Volume = Current OBV
> 2. If Current Closing Price is less than the Prior Closing Price then:    Previous OBV - Current Volume = Current OBV
> 3. If Current Closing Price is equal to the Prior Closing Price then:    Previous OBV = Current OBV

Python code that i tried:

```
def on_balance_volume(close_data, volume):
    """
    On Balance Volume.
    Formula:
    start = 1
    if CLOSEt > CLOSEt-1
        obv = obvt-1 + volumet
    elif CLOSEt < CLOSEt-1
        obv = obvt-1 - volumet
    elif CLOSEt == CLOSTt-1
        obv = obvt-1
    """
    catch_errors.check_for_input_len_diff(close_data, volume)
    obv = np.zeros(len(volume))
    obv[0] = 0
    for idx in range(0, len(obv)):
        if (close_data[idx] - close_data[idx-1]) > 0:
            obv[idx] = obv[idx-1] + volume[idx]
        elif (close_data[idx] - close_data[idx-1])<0:
            obv[idx] = obv[idx-1] - volume[idx]
#        elif close_data[idx] == close_data[idx-1]:
#            obv[idx] = obv[idx-1]
    return obv


df['obv']=on_balance_volume(df['close'],df['volume'])
```

> Note : I verified the volume input that is matching exactly what is
>   shown in tradingview.

you can use this data source for verifying the output (Generate your key to get the data)
[DateLink](http://'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=NSE:ADANIPORTS&apikey=key&outputsize=full&datatype=csv')

What is the change i need to do to get the exact TV chart OBV value in python code.

Comment: i have the exact same question! did you figure out how to transfer that line over to python?